# android intent has other flags

Tags: android, android-intent

i am new to android developing and i am looking at the code of the guy who worked here before. I check to connect to a server. That works great (see D/ConnectivityChecker(29802):  isOnline=true). Then i create a new Intent and set a flag (public static int ONLINE_FLAG = 1) as you can see in intent.setFlags 1. Then i send this intent via sendBroadcast to my connectionChangeReceiver.

And if i read out the intents flag it is not 1 it is 17!

This is the code of the connectionChangeReceiver:

```
/**
 * Receives notifications about connectivity changes
 */
private BroadcastReceiver connectionChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("connectionChangeReceiver","Intent.Flags(): '" + intent.getFlags() + "' ICM.ONLINE_FLAG: '" + InternetConnectionManager.ONLINE_FLAG+"'");
        setOnlineMode(intent.getFlags() == ICM.ONLINE_FLAG);
    }

};
```

This is the logcat:

```
05-08 14:28:05.615: V/ICM(29802): checkConnectivity
05-08 14:28:05.615: V/ICM(29802): ConnectivityChecker.execute()
05-08 14:28:05.620: D/ConnectivityChecker(29802): doInBackground
05-08 14:28:05.620: D/ConnectivityChecker(29802): Host: 192.168.2.109 Port:8000
05-08 14:28:05.670: V/ICM(29802): checkConnectivity
05-08 14:28:08.670: D/ConnectivityChecker(29802):  isOnline=true
05-08 14:28:08.670: D/ConnectivityChecker(29802): intent.setFlags 1
05-08 14:28:08.670: D/ConnectivityChecker(29802): sendBroadcast(intent)
05-08 14:28:08.675: D/connectionChangeReceiver(29802): Intent.Flags(): '17' ICM.ONLINE_FLAG: '1'
```

The intentFlag is set by the ConnectivityChecker to 1 but the connectionChangeReceiver gets a 17. And i dont know why?

I check it twice. This is the only part of code where an Intent will be created and the function setFlags() will be called. The variable ONLINE_FLAG is set to "public static int ONLINE_FLAG = 1;" its the same variable i can call with ICM.ONLINE_FLAG.

I dont know why the intent's Flag is 17 ??

Maybe someone can help me to fix it.

EDIT:
Sorry i forgot the code to create the intent:

```
private class ConnectivityChecker extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.d("ConnectivityChecker","doInBackground");
            Socket socket = null;
            boolean online = false;
            try {
                Log.d("ConnectivityChecker","Host: "+ConnectionHandler.host+" Port:"+ConnectionHandler.port);
                socket = new Socket();
                socket.bind(null);
                InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(ConnectionHandler.host, ConnectionHandler.port);
                socket.connect(address, TIMEOUT * 1000);
                online = socket.isConnected();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Nothing to do since we are just interested in the
                // availability of the server
            }
            Log.d("ConnectivityChecker"," isOnline=" + online);
            Log.d("ConnectivityChecker"," new Intent (" + CONNECTIVITY_ACTION+")");
            Intent intent = new Intent(CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
            if (online){
                intent.setFlags(ONLINE_FLAG);
                Log.d("ConnectivityChecker","intent.setFlags " + ONLINE_FLAG);

            }

            isServerAvailable = online;

            Log.d("ConnectivityChecker","sendBroadcast(intent)");
            sendBroadcast(intent);

            return null;
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setFlag() and getFlags() are for [specialized flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29), not for custom boolean data. In your case your need to use

```
intent.putExtra ( "tag", boolean_flag_sent );
```

and in your receiving place

```
boolean_flag_received = intent.getBooleanExtra( "tag", false );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,I don't understand you problem correctly. But from what I understand Intent.getFlags() will give you an integer value which represent the number of special flags associated with the  intent itself. In your case it is 17. 
                The code shown above will not create any new intent rather you are passing the created intent from other code. Check the code from where this method is called and what intent is passed

Comment: sorry i forgot the code to create the intent and send it via sendBroadcast. I added it. If i set the intent via intent.setFlags(1) why intent.getFlags() = 17?